# How can I unlock my manual focus ring?

Tags: nikon, autofocus

The manual focus ring on my 18-200mm lens is totaly unmovable.

I have tried attaching other lenses to my camera and they work, so I am thinking that there must be an issue with my lens. I have tried attaching the lens to another camera and it still did not work. The switch is on auto mode and i am trying to switch it to manual but it won't let me; it's stuck in auto mode, and I am unable to move the ring. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the auto/manual switch doesn't lock anything. Rather, in auto mode, it just allows your camera body to override the human operating the focus ring.

That fact both the switch and the ring are seized implies the lens needs servicing.